# Default array displaying undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

The following Javascript function is displaying `undefined` value when it should display the actual value:

```
<script>
    function addArrayNew(a = [101], c) {
        document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }

    addArrayNew(110);
</script>
```

Actual Output:

```
A: undefined
B: 110
C: undefined
```

Expected Output:

```
A: 101
B: 101
C: 110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening as the function description for `addArrayNew` has `a` as first argument and `c` as second argument. So, whatever you pass at first value for `addArrayNew(110)` that will be set for `a` only and if you pass `addArrayNew(110, 100)` that would be set for a first and then c. If you want to send 2nd parameter only and want `a` to set as default then you can pass `undefined` like:

```js
function addArrayNew(a = [101], c) {
  document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
  document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
  document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
}

addArrayNew(undefined, 110);
```

By passing `undefined`, we are actually forcing `a` to use the default value instead. But good practice is to always use optional parameters are last, so that by default they are set to `undefined` like:

```js
function addArrayNew(c, a = [101]) {
  document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
  document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
  document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
}

addArrayNew(110);
```

Here, using `addArrayNew(110)` or `addArrayNew(110, undefined)` will give you same result. But you can really understand the importance of using default values at last when you will have a large number of params to a function like:

```js
function addArrayNew(a, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5) {
  document.write(`${a} - ${b} - ${c} - ${d} - ${e} - ${f}`);
}

addArrayNew(110);
```

As you see by putting the optional values at last, we have only call function like `addArrayNew(110)` instead of doing `addArrayNew(undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined, 110)` if `a` was at last.

Answer (score 2):

In your example `110` gets passed as first (and only) argument so it overwrites `a` insted of `c` (which will become `undefined`). It's better to put optional parameters as the last ones and then you can pass more or less arguments to your function:

```html
<script>
    function addArrayNew(c, a = [101]) {
        document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }

    addArrayNew(110);
</script>
```

Comment: But then how come `B: 110` is displayed in actual output? It should be `B: undefined` instead

Comment: `a.toString()` on single-element array will return the only value

Comment: "_But then how come B: 110 is displayed in actual output? It should be B: undefined instead_" because you have passed `a` as `110` which is a number thus `110` is shown for b, but as `a` is a number it not an array thus `a[0]` is undefined.